# How does Angular2 Universal handle ajax calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-universal

I've been using Angula2 + Universal from the day one they launched it, but today I'm getting confused around how it actually works.

In their [example](https://github.com/angular/universal.git) , in the server.ts file you will find :

```
app.get( '/data.json' , ( req , res ) => {
    res.json( {
        data : 'This fake data came from the server.'
    } );
} );
```

If you run the app , right click and view page source , you'll find 'This fake data came from the server' in the source code , meaning that the page got rendered in the server ? ( Is this correct ? )

So far , so great.

Next is in the app.ts , you can find :

```
ngOnInit () {
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.server = 'This was rendered from the server!';
        } , 10 );
}
```

Again , this text can be found in the page source as well.

Now here is the weird  part for me :

If you , for any reason , increase the server latency like :

```
app.get( '/data.json' , ( req , res ) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
        res.json( {
            data : 'This fake data came from the server.'
        } );
    } , 2000 ); // Added setTimeOut with 2 seconds .
} );
```

This way , the page source wont get the text , however , if you do this :

```
app.get( '/data.json' , ( req , res ) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
        res.json( {
            data : 'This fake data came from the server.'
        } );
    } , 2 ); // **Added setTimeOut with 2 milli seconds.**
} );
```

This one, you can find the text in the server .!!!!!!

So far based on my tests , I'm guessing if the ajax call latency is to long ( more than one second I guess ? ) , you won't benefit from server side rendering .

BUT :

However , if you increase the timeOut in the app.component.ts , like :

```
ngOnInit () {
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.server = 'This was rendered from the server!';
        } , 3000 );  // Increased to 3 seconds
}
```

You can still get the server side rendering and source page will have the text rendered !

What's happening here ?

Obviously not all of the ajax calls can be lower than 1 seconds , so what is the benefit of using universal anyway ?

Comment: If you want to solve your problem, the solution is to place the request logic in the route guard or route resolver. That actually gets executed for sure.